# lightningd wont work: SQLITE version mismatch: compiled 3036000, now 3032003

Tags: lightning-network, core-lightning, lightning-nodes

I installed bitcoind and trying to run lightningd through this guide: https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/blob/master/doc/INSTALL.md#to-build-on-macos.

I did everything it says. Bitcoin node is running, blokcs are up to date but when I do  "./lightningd/lightningd", it throws a message: "SQLITE version mismatch: compiled 3036000, now 3032003".

How do I fix this and run a lightning node?

Answer (score 2):

Since losing the database could lead to loss of funds, C-lightning is a bit conservative and will only accept to start against a SQLite runtime dependency of the same version it was compiled with.

To solve this issue, just recompile `lightningd`.

Comment: Can you tell me which step is this on the link? Because I might have just done that. Os is Macos. Link: https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/blob/master/doc/INSTALL.md#to-build-on-macos

Comment: Did you update your system in-between the time you compiled `lightningd` and the time you tried to run it?

Comment: Yes I might have. I tried so many thing so I'm not sure.

Comment: Then just re-compile `lightningd` as suggested in the answer..

Comment: I did recompile still the same :(